# Subtracting values between groups within a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to calculate the differences between two groups that may have mismatched data in an efficient manner.

The following dataframe, `df`,

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'type': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'W', 'W', 'W'],
                   'code': ['1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '4'],
                   'values': [50, 25, 25, 50, 10, 40]})
```

has two types that have mismatched "codes" -- notably code 3  is not present for the 'W' type and code 4 is not present for the 'A' type. I have wrapped codes as strings as in my particular case they are sometimes strings.

I would like to substract the values for matching codes between the two types so that we obtain,

```
result = pd.DataFrame({'code': ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
                       'diff': [0, 15, 25, -40]})
```

Where the sign would indicate which type had the greater value.

I have spent some time examining variations on groupby diff methods here, but have not seen anything that deals with the particular issue of subtracting between two potentially mismatched columns. Instead, most questions appear to be appropriate for the intended use of the diff() method.

The route I've tried most recently is using a list comprehension on the `df.groupby['type']` to split into two dataframes, but then I remain with a similar problem regarding subtracting mismatched cases.

Comment: Your `values` in `df` is wrong. There are 7 values there instead of 6, please drop one. If you need empty cells somewhere, please add them as `' '`

Comment: And how did you calculate the `-40` for code `4`?

Comment: Please fix your input

Comment: Corrected the values, thanks.

0 - 40 = -40 since there is no code 4 for type A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groupby on code, then substitute the missing value with 0

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'type': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'W', 'W', 'W'],
                   'code': ['1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '4'],
                   'values': [50, 25, 25, 50, 10, 40]})

def my_func(x):
    # What if there are more than 1 value for a type/code combo?
    a_value = x[x.type == 'A']['values'].max() 
    w_value = x[x.type == 'W']['values'].max()

    a_value = 0 if np.isnan(a_value) else a_value
    w_value = 0 if np.isnan(w_value) else w_value
    return a_value - w_value

df_new = df.groupby('code').apply(my_func)

df_new = df_new.reset_index()
df_new = df_new.rename(columns={0:'diff'})

print(df_new)

  code  diff
0    1     0
1    2    15
2    3    25
3    4   -40
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate anticipating the duplication issue as well.